# Underscore nested each loops with Backbone Views

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

Trying to nest the rendering of each measureView, and its children (the beatView(s)) in the same measureView.js file.   We are using require.js for path definitions, so forgive some of the undefined var names.   The problem is in measuresView.js, in the nested _.each method, as the `new BeatView()` returns `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.   We tried manually calling the `new BeatView()` from outside the first `_.each function` to make sure that it wasn't scoping of the require.js BeatView variable, but got the same error using this: (`new BeatView({model:this.component.models[0].get('beats').models[0], el:this.el});`
).   Is there something special to using nested `_.each`s with scoping, or something else I am missing?

measuresView.js:
[jsfiddle of complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/MnFDR/)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/collections/beats',
  'backbone/collections/measures',
  'backbone/views/beats/beatView',
  'text!backbone/templates/measures/audioMeasures.html',
  'text!backbone/templates/measures/linearBarMeasures.html',
  'text!backbone/templates/measures/linearBarSVGMeasures.html',
  'text!backbone/templates/measures/circularPieMeasures.html',
  'app/dispatch',
  'app/state',
  'app/log'
], function($, _, Backbone, BeatsCollection, MeasuresCollection, BeatView, audioMeasuresTemplate, linearBarMeasuresTemplate, linearBarSVGMeasuresTemplate, circularPieMeasuresTemplate, dispatch, state, log){
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.component'),
```

...

```
render: function(){
  //we create a measuresView for each measure.
  _.each(this.component.models, function(measure) {
    var compiledTemplate = _.template( this.representations[this.currentMeasureRepresentation], {measure: measure, measureAngle: 360.0 } );
    $(this.el).append( compiledTemplate );
       //we create a beatView for each beat in the measure.
        _.each(measure.get('beats').models, function(beat) {
          new BeatView({model:beat, el:this.el});
        }, this);
  }, this);
 return this;
},
```

beatView.js :
[jsfiddle of complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/b4yRA/)

```
render: function(){
  var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.representations[this.currentBeatRepresentation], {beat: this.model, beatAngle: this.beatAngle});
  $(this.el).append(compiledTemplate);
  return this;
},
```

Additional Info:

Backbone Structure:

```
Component (basically an instrument)
  ↳ A collection of Measure(s)
    ↳ Measure
      ↳ A collection of Beat(s)
        ↳ Beat
```

beat Model:

```
//filename: models/beat.js
/*
  This is the beat model.
  It only knows about whether or not it
  is selected.
*/
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
  var beatModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      selected: false,
      state: 'OFF'
    },
    initialize: function(){
    },
    getStyleClass: function() {
      if (this.selected) {
        return 'ON';
      }
      else {
        return 'OFF';
      }
    }
  });
  return beatModel;
});
```

beat collection:

```
//Filename: collections/beats.js
/*
  This is the beats collection.
  It is a collection of beat models.
*/
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/models/beat'
], function($, _, Backbone, beatModel){
  return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: beatModel,
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });
  //return new beatsCollection();
});
```

measure model :

```
//filename: models/measure.js
/*
  This is the measure model.
  A component has a collection of these models.
  these models have a collection of beats.
*/
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/collections/beats'
], function(_, Backbone, beatsCollection) {
  var measureModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      label: '0/4',
      beats: beatsCollection,
      numberOfBeats: 0,
      divisions: 8
    },
    initialize: function(){     
    }
  });
  return measureModel;
});
```

measure collection :

```
//filename collections/measures.js
/*
  This is the measures collection.
  It is a collection of measure models.
*/
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/models/measure'
], function($, _, Backbone, measureModel){
  return Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: measureModel,
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });
});
```

Inside error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function measuresView.js:100
(anonymous function) measuresView.js:100
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
(anonymous function) measuresView.js:96
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
Backbone.View.extend.render measuresView.js:88
Backbone.View.extend.initialize measuresView.js:72
Backbone.View backbone.js:1236
child backbone.js:1467
Backbone.View.extend.render componentView.js:63
Backbone.View.extend.initialize componentView.js:54
Backbone.View backbone.js:1236
child backbone.js:1467
(anonymous function) componentsView.js:201
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
Backbone.View.extend.render componentsView.js:192
Backbone.Router.extend.newSong router.js:42
(anonymous function) backbone.js:967
(anonymous function) backbone.js:1164
_.some._.any underscore.js:207
_.extend.loadUrl backbone.js:1162
_.extend.start backbone.js:1128
initialize router.js:157
initialize SOF.js:15
....
```

Outside error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function measuresView.js:86
Backbone.View.extend.render measuresView.js:86
Backbone.View.extend.initialize measuresView.js:72
Backbone.View backbone.js:1236
child backbone.js:1467
Backbone.View.extend.render componentView.js:63
Backbone.View.extend.initialize componentView.js:54
Backbone.View backbone.js:1236
child backbone.js:1467
(anonymous function) componentsView.js:201
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
Backbone.View.extend.render componentsView.js:192
Backbone.Router.extend.newSong router.js:42
(anonymous function) backbone.js:967
(anonymous function) backbone.js:1164
_.some._.any underscore.js:207
_.extend.loadUrl backbone.js:1162
_.extend.start backbone.js:1128
initialize router.js:157
initialize SOF.js:15
....
```

Comment: So you did get the same error when you try `new BeatView()` outside of the loops?

Comment: yes.   which doesn't make sense that it wouldn't have access to it, as it is in the require  (posted now)

Comment: errors posted as well

Comment: So the problem is that `BeatView` is undefined. This can happen with requirejs if you have circular dependencies, and maybe script errors in the module. Does `BeatView` have the `MeasuresView` module in its dependency list?

Comment: It does not, but I think you are on to something....   working through it....

Comment: Maybe kinda late, but could you post a jsfiddle or pastebin with the whole code of `BeatView`?

Comment: @Loamhoof Posted,   I think I found an error, and am now looking into the nested loops interaction with dispatch.....

Comment: As it was bugging me that I couldn't find anything wrong with the code you provided I've run a few tests (I didn't know how require reacts to different errors). The only thing that would make sense (having this undefined error) would be that your beatView file actually doesn't return a class. If you return anything else than a function, you'll get an undefined as you get. But the code you posted should have no error. Could you try to create a beatView inside you beatView file before returning it to verify you really have a function?

Comment: @PaulHoenecke put your comment in answer...   that pointed me in the right direction....